# How does the concept of a "buff" work in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, gramática, adjetivos

I am writing about hobbies. The hobbies are being listed as short headlines, with an article to accompany the headline.

In English, I would use the term "buff" to make it more obvious what the heading is referring to.

For example:

- Architecture Buff
- Geography Buff
- History Buff
- Archeology Buff
- Train Buff

Would this 'buff' concept translate to Spanish, or am I better of just listing the activities in the heading, without using the word 'buff'.

#### Research I have done.

1. [Spanish dict lists](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/buff) **aficionado**, **entusiasta**, **fanático** as equivalents.
   “aficionado a la arquitectura“, “aficionado a la geografía“, “aficionado a la historia“, "aficionado a la arqueología",  etc seem to generate good results. But the rest do not.
2. On the [Spanish entry for Trains](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tren) on Wikipedia they list '**entusiasta** del tren', but it links to the English article.

On the basis of this research, I am certain that “aficionado a la arquitectura“, “aficionado del tren“, “aficionado a la geografía“ would be fine. However, as I am not a native speaker, I would appreciate native input if such wordings are acceptable or if a Spanish native would just list the activity without qualifying it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, the translation of "buff" (in the sense of "hobbyist") is *[aficionado](https://dle.rae.es/aficionado)*, *[entusiasta](https://dle.rae.es/entusiasta)*, or *[fanático](https://dle.rae.es/fan%C3%A1tico)*, where *aficionado* is less strong than *entusiasta*, which is in turn less strong than *fanático*.

Whether you list the activities with or without the qualifying "aficionados" depends mostly on your writing style and on what you are writing about. If I were writing about the hobbies themselves, I would just use the names of the activities as headings. If I were writing about the people who practise these activities (the *buffs* themselves), I would probably use headings with the word "aficionados" in plural, as in "Aficionados a la arquitectura", "Aficionados al ferrocarril", etc. This is mostly to make the headings correspond to what is in the text: I would find it strange to see a paragraph with heading "Aficionados al ferrocarril" that only talks about trains.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply state the Headings without "buff" if you are only using the word to emphasize the space between the words. Concepts are very difficult to translate literally.